# how to delete repeated elements from a sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, bubble-sort

As you can see here this is a program which is to sort elements in ascending order and delete any repeated elements. The problem here is with the 'delete' snippet. It works for an array of 5 elements where the values(1,3,3,5,5) are in any order because the 'sort' snippet takes care of that. However if you take a sequence say(1,1,1,2,1,3) the deletion does not take place completely. Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

class Random 
{ 
 
 static int count=2;
public static void main(String[] args)          
{
    
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many elements are in your set?");// gets your elements
        int input=sc.nextInt();
       
        int Subsets=No_of_subsets(input);
        // to accept elements
        int arr[]=new int[input+2];
        accept(arr);
        //to sort and delete repeated elements

        sortanddelete(arr);
        System.out.println("Array a=");
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length-count;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
  System.out.println("Count"+count);
}
public static int No_of_subsets(int a )
{
    double ab=Math.pow(2, a);
    int ans=(int)ab;
    System.out.println("Your superset will have "+ans+" subsets");
    return (int)ans;
}

public static int[] accept(int a[])
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your array elements");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-2;i++){
        a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
    return a;
}

public static int[] sortanddelete(int a[])
{
    int temp;
    for(int i=a.length-3;i>0;i--){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    

    
    for(int i=0;i<a.length-count;i++){
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
            for(int j=i;j<a.length-count;j++){
            a[j]=a[j+1];
        }
        count++;
    }
    }
    

    return a;
}


}
```

Comment: looks like a good point to read /learn java collections....

Comment: using Set datatype instead of arraylist

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work because your bubble sort is wrong. You're starting at `a.length-3` and going down, which means that the last two items in the array are never sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only  need to change your delete for loop as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length-count;){
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
            for(int j=i;j<a.length-count;j++){
               a[j]=a[j+1];
            }
            count++;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
 }
```

Because if you always do i++ (even when all the elements were shifted), then you miss some repetitions. Actually, when a shifting is done it is like i has been incremented. So, you only need to increment i when the if doesn't happen.

Comment: I ran this code just now. That's the only change I made. And for input (1, 1, 1, 2 , 1, 3) it works properly. Can you check again? The output should be 1 2 3, right?

Comment: Remember you should remove i++ from the for loop

Comment: Mashregi thanks a lot you are a life saver. Solved like a boss thanks :)